# Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Only 4D tensors in BHWD layout are supported

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a project where I use my own tflite model, and trying to implement it into the github project example of TensorFlow itself, Object Detection. I use Android studio to run this project.

When I use my own model, it gives me the error as shown below:
[image: Error]

I tried many things but to no avail. Link to the model and the project are given below.
Would appreciate any help given.

(link to project:https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection)

(link to download model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eOzjMTnT5btEhXZ1ABZ4Mv4NzmmsBaGT/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Your model doesn't fit the TFLite object detection reference app. The input is a tensor of shape [1,5,126], which doesn't seem to be an image. The output is a tensor of shape [1, 12], which doesn't seem to be an object detection output either.

The supported model format can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview#model_description).